# Bootstrap data-target panel close outside of data-parent nest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column-8 with a panel section list of check boxes, then on the right a column-4 list of information for that specific panel section.

I decided I want one panel open at a time by using `data-parent` which allows me do that.

Within that same panel trigger element I define two data-targets. ex `<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#design,#collapseDesign">`

The issue is the data-target outside of the `data-parent` within the column-4 is not being closed properly. Which is obvious why it's not, but how do I write it so bootstrap knows to close the target?

http://jsfiddle.net/n353v9at/

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#design,#collapseDesign">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Design</h4>
                        <i class="ti-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>

            <div id="collapseDesign" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="Order[psd]" />
                                <label for="c1"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">PSD</div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-tip" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 25px;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Do you have a PSD file that you would like to be converted into code?" class="ti-more-alt"></span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-desc" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You have your own photoshop mockup</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c2"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">Custom</div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-tip" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 25px;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Let us handle your design, we will submit mockups, this option will cost more." class="ti-more-alt"></span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-service-desc" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You want us to come up with a design concept</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#demo,#collapseOne">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Markup</h4>
                        <i class="ti-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c1"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">PSD</div>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You have your own photoshop mockup...</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c2"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">Custom</div>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You want us to come up with a concept...</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="info-preferences">
        <div id="design" class="collapse in">
            <p>Describe the design process</p>
        </div>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            <p>Describe the markup process</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a pure bootstrap way to handle this or do I need to create a custom method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use an id to identify the element you should try to do it with the same class:
http://jsfiddle.net/n353v9at/1/

HTML CODE (i changed `data-target="#design,#collapseDesign"` for `data-target=".collapseDesign"` and i added this class to the elements that you desired to close)

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target=".collapseDesign">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Design</h4>
                        <i class="ti-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>

            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in collapseDesign">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="Order[psd]" />
                                <label for="c1"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">PSD</div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-tip" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 25px;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Do you have a PSD file that you would like to be converted into code?" class="ti-more-alt"></span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-desc" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You have your own photoshop mockup</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c2"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">Custom</div>
                                    <div class="psd-service-tip" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 25px;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Let us handle your design, we will submit mockups, this option will cost more." class="ti-more-alt"></span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-service-desc" style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You want us to come up with a design concept</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#demo,#collapseOne">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Markup</h4>
                        <i class="ti-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c1"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">PSD</div>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You have your own photoshop mockup...</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
                                <label for="c2"> <span class="box"><span class="typcn typcn-tick"></span></span>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #000">Custom</div>
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; color: #64687b;font-size: 12px;float: right;">You want us to come up with a concept...</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="info-preferences">
        <div class="collapse in collapseDesign">
            <p>Describe the design process</p>
        </div>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            <p>Describe the markup process</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, i dont know why in the second case bootstrap works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it still does the same thing. Try clicking "markup" first, you will see there are two info items open on the right.